# Make a regex to unmatch a specific email case

Tags: javascript, regex

While validating an EMAIL with a regex, since the expression cannot be substitute with a copy&paste from RFC 2822, I have to modify this:

```
^\.*[^\s]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$
```

to make it **unmatch** this case:

```
test@test
```

Here's the link: https://regex101.com/r/RGvyHk/2

Comment: [Replace the last `*` with `+` to require at least 1 occurrence of `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/e9Lmyr/1). Is the ``\`` after `^` a typo? Did you mean to match a literal dot at the start?

Comment: I'm quite newbie to regex I thought it was some kind of expression to say "every character" but removing it it's working good so that's implicit i see...

Comment: Every char can be matchedf with `[\s\S]` or `[^]`. A `.` matches any char but line break chars (not `\n`, `\r`, etc.). `/\./` will match a literal full stop char since the `.` is escaped. In your pattern, `\.*` matches zero or more full stops. So, [`.....@test` can be matched](https://regex101.com/r/RGvyHk/3), for example.

Comment: Good one, thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last `*` with `+` to require at least 1 occurrence of `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` pattern.

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$
                                             ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e9Lmyr/1).

Note that this pattern is too restrictive. You should consider using a much more permissive pattern like `/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/` that just requires `@` enclosed with 1+ non-whitespace symbols and then a dot followed with 1+ non-whitespaces. Note that this pattern still won't allow spaces in the email, though spaces are also allowed.